# Flutter Future Returns Null from API

Tags: flutter

I don't seem to know whats wrong with this code . it returns nothing

```
Future<Product> fetchProducts() async {
final response =
await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/products'));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
// print(response.body);
return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
} else {
throw Exception('Failed to load products');
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show the api and Product model?

Comment: class Product {
  int id;
  int userId;
  int quantity;
  int price;
  String product_condition;
  String description;
  String product_image;
  String created_at;
  String updated_at;
  String product_name;

Comment: Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.quantity,
    required this.price,
    required this.product_condition,
    required this.description,
    required this.product_image,
    required this.created_at,
    required this.updated_at,
    required this.product_name,
  });

Comment: factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
        id: json['id'],
        userId: json['user_id'],
        quantity: json['quantity'],
        price: json['price'],
        product_condition: json['product_condition'],
        description: json['description'],
        product_image: json['product_image'],
        created_at: json['created_at'],
        updated_at: json['updated_at'],
        product_name: json['product_name']);
  }
}

Comment: am not sure u can see that well

Comment: You can check here sir
https://jsfiddle.net/tv3yof5d/

Comment: What do you get when you print the response: `print(response.body)`?

Comment: I got the right response

Comment: Did you somehow assisted jsonDecode to decode the JSON and create object from that? Dart doesn't create objects here by magic.

Comment: @SteAp do you mean this
return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));

Comment: Yes. jsonDecode() decodes JSON data, but you need to provide methods to create objects.